# How to resend pictures in telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

There is a code that forwards messages from one group to another.

```
history = await tg_client(GetHistoryRequest(
                peer=channel,
                offset_id=0,
                offset_date=None, add_offset=0,
                limit=1, max_id=0, min_id=0,
                hash=0))
            messages = history.messages
            if last_message_id != messages[0].id:
                last_message_id = messages[0].id
                print(str(messages[0].message))
                await tg_client.send_message('user_id', str(messages[0].message+"\n\n\n sent by bot"))
```

But if there are pictures in the post, it ignores them and sends only the text, if there is no text, but only a picture, then it does not send anything. How can I make it send an image as well?

I tried to search the documentation for the option I needed, but I did not find anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

You must either use `tg_client.send_file` when there's media, or pass the `message` object (not `message.message`, which is the string text) to `send_message`, which will copy the values (won't work on channels with restricted content).